# React-select default behaviour and custom looking

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am very new in react and in react-select too. While trying to implement a custom looking component I read a lot of information, but it is not so user friendly IMHO.

1. I want my react-select component to show selected data in a row. Now it shows them in columns, I attached the picture.

BTW what is the purpose of name, label fields? What is the exact difference?

```
<Select
  defaultValue={[models[0], models[1]]}
  isMulti
  options={models}
  className="select-custom-class"
  name="form-field-name"
  options={models}
  placeholder="Model: "
/>
```

[image: this is my current ugly react-select multi]

2. I want to do some "chips style" dropdown VIA react-select. Is it possible? What style options I have to specify to round the corners like on the picture? I also want to add some static text inside the chips to be shown always: for example (regarding the pic below) "City: $here_come_the_values"

[image: this is what I want]

Maybe I should use another react component? The ending purpose of those dropdowns are to make filtering to the table, so I want to link them with react-bootstrap-table2.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Ok, the round style   ` const Styles = {
        control: (base, state) => ({
            ...base,
            borderRadius: '16px',
            '&:hover':
                {
                    border: '1px solid #0679A8',
                }
        }),`  The still question is how to maintain static text in react-select when there options are selected, why my multi looks so bad when selecting and the diff between value, default value, name and label, I really can't get this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ugliness because of the width. Why I need className to be set in <Select className = '****'  if I can do styles by styles = {Styles} in options? What is the difference between those appoaches? Is the className full css supportive?

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually I found how to make a nice-looking ONE LINE select component with dots in the end (like spread operator or ellipsis)
with modern react-jsx syntax without this

```
            <Select
                defaultValue={defaultValues}
                closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                isMulti
                options={defaultValues}
                components={{
                    IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
                    DropdownIndicator,
                    ClearIndicator,
                    MultiValueContainer: multiValueContainer
                }}
```

and here we return all the values

```
const multiValueContainer = (props) => {
    const label = props.data.label;
    const allSelected = props.selectProps.value;
    const index = allSelected.findIndex(selected => selected.label === label);
    const isLastSelected = index === allSelected.length - 1;
    const labelSuffix = isLastSelected ? ` (${allSelected.length})` : ", ";
    const val = `${label}${labelSuffix}`;
    return val;
};
```

and the style

```
const styles = {
    control: (base, state) => ({
        ...base,
        borderRadius: '16px',
        border: '1px solid #E5F7FF',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        boxSizing: 'border - box',
        wordWrap: "break-word",
        '&:hover':
            {
                border: '1px solid #0679A8',
            }
    }),
    valueContainer: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        textOverflow: "ellipsis",
        maxWidth: "90%",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        overflow: "hidden",
        display: "initial"
    })
};
```